# Add a field into JSON array

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

I got a JSON string with an array like this:

```
 {
  "Id": 123,
  "Username": "Sr. X",
  "Packages": [
    {
      "Name": "Cups",
      "SupplierId": 1,
      "ProviderGroupId": 575,
      "SupplierName": "Foo Cups"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Pins",
      "SupplierId": 5,
      "ProviderGroupId": 1082,
      "SupplierName": "Foo Pins"
    }
  ]
}
```

and I want to add a new field into Packages array like:

```
"Packages": [
    {
      "Name": "Cups",
      "SupplierId": 1,
      "ProviderGroupId": 575,
      "SupplierName": "Foo Cups",
      "New Field": "Value"
    },...
```

Right now I can add a new field but in the main object, I'm using Json.NET library to do the job, but it seems that the documentation doesn't reach that level.

Have any one of you done it before?

Comment: Can you not just serialize the "main object" again with `JsonConvert.SerializeObject();` after adding the new object to the collection?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? The Json.NET documentation is pretty clear about how to [add properties to `JObject`s](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Add.htm)...

Comment: I'm receiving a string with a JSON structure (the first snippet) but what I want is to add a new field and value to it, to then parse it to a xml, but that part I have done it already

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JObject implemets IDictionary.

```
var jObj = JObject.Parse(json);
foreach(var item in jObj["Packages"])
{
    item["New Field"] = "Value";
}
var newjson = jObj.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer L.B. that worked. Is haven't worked with JSON before and I thought it was about time so I started to practicing, now I know a little bit more.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
JObject root = (JObject) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(File.ReadAllText("products.json"));
JArray packages = (JArray) root["Packages"];

JObject newItem = new JObject();
newItem["Name"] = "Cups";
// ...

packages.Add(newItem);

Console.WriteLine(root); // Prints new json
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but LB approach worked for me. Cheers!