# Add a field into JSON array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, foreach

Here is my json Array, i want to add a new field in array but i dont know how to loop it

```
{
    "data": {
        "pasca": [
            {
                "code": "PDI1231",
                "name": "Water Bottle",
                "status": 1,
                "price": 2500,
                "type": "plastic"
            },
            {
                "code": "PDI9999",
                "name": "Soccel Ball",
                "status": 1,
                "price": 99123,
                "type": "plastic"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

i want to add a new field in pasca array like this

```
"pasca": [
            {
                "code": "PDI1231",
                "name": "Water Bottle",
                "status": 1,
                "price": 2500,
                "type": "plastic",
                "new_field_1": "new value_1",
                "new_field_2": "new value_2"
            }
        ]
```

Comment: What have you tried, what library do you use?

Comment: 1) Deserialize the JSON (even into a JSON.NET JObject, for example), 2) Add the new array items. 3) Serialize the JSON.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add a field into JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39416530/add-a-field-into-json-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Newtosoft's Json.NET it can be done as simple as that:

```
var jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json);
foreach(var el in jObj["data"]["pasca"])
{
    el["new_field_1"] = "new value_1";
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, where do you get that documentation for looping like that ?

Comment: @MAndreJuliansyah Was glad to help! Newtonsoft has pretty extensive [documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm).